# Is it possible to use quarkus security with quarkus-smallrye-graphql?

Tags: graphql, quarkus, smallrye

I am trying to use the quarkus-smallrye-graphql extension. And it seems like I cannot use any of the security annotations such as **@Authenticated** in a class annotated with **@GraphQLApi**. I previously tried to use the smallrye-graphql project directly and I was able to use security. But now when using the offered extension in quarkus, it does not work.

A simple example of api class is

```
@GraphQLApi
public class SomeApi {
    @Query
    @Authenticated
    public String testQuery() {
        return "hello...";
    }
}
```

This does not work with the extension and I always get the unauthorized exception. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension is not properly integrated with programmatic security yet. Please follow https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10001 that I've reported, it should be fixed soon.

In the meantime, it is possible to use config-based security as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/security#authorization-of-web-endpoints-using-configuration, just use `/graphql*` for the `quarkus.http.auth.permission.roles1.paths` property